# Jhipster with react update some fields in a form

Tags: reactjs, jhipster

I have used Jhipster with react, and I have a form with many fields.

In the form, I have a button to triggered an endpoint to get some data
Then with this data, I need to update some fields in the form.

But I don't know how to do this.

I will appreciate any insight about how to do it !!